# Removing the default help command on discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I have searched multiple places and they all say to do the same thing but the default help command still shows up when I run the command. I get the message `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found` on the print line but still get the help message on discord.

This is at the top of my script right under imports.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
client.remove_command('help')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [discordpy documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.help_command), setting `help_command` to `None` when declaring the client solves ths issue.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', help_command=None)
```

Comment: I think I tried this but I’ll give it another go when I get home

Answer (score 0):

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "#")
client.remove_command("help")
```

Also works